# electron-forge better-sqlite3 - TypeError: Cannot open database because the directory does not exist

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron, electron-forge, better-sqlite3

I have a [Typescript + Webpack](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template) boilerplate from electron-forge.

I store my data with `better-sqlite3`. And copy the database file with `copy-webpack-plugin` like this:

```js
plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "src/data/db.db", to: "../data/db.db" }
      ],
    }),
  ],
```

I then get my data base in my `index.ts` file like this:

```js
const dbPath = isDevEnv
    ? path.join(app.getAppPath(), "src", "data", "db.db")
    : path.join("resources", "app", ".webpack", "data", "db.db");

const db = new Database(dbPath, { verbose: console.log });
```

It is working okay when running locally, and also when running `npm run make`. But once I install or uninstall the app, it errors:

image: [A Javascript error occured in the main process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PdzX.png)

```
A Javascript error occured in the main process
Uncaught exception:
TypeError: Cannot open database because the directory does not exist
```

While it errors like this, it installs the app okay on my desktop. It runs and is fetching data from the database. Anyone knows why it errors when installing and uninstalling?

Comment: Not sure how you handled validation and all. But in case of lack of proper validation during installation and uninstallation event, it might throwing the error. Please check that basic level of validations are implemented.  Also verify that you are closing db connection once you are done with any DB operation.

Comment: I see, for that I'm not familiar with validation, is this validation for sql? I have not implemented any validations I think, where can I read more of validation? 

For closing db, I `db.close()` on window close since users are going to read and write when the app is open.